# Duplication content directory without redirect .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

There is a page on the way:

```
site.com/page
```

Need to make it available in several locations, for example:

```
site.com/site 
site.com/to
```

How to do? Without redirect, to display content

Comment: I would not recommend doing this - it is bad practice for SEO, and Google (and other search engines) will see it as duplicate content.

Comment: Are you using php or pure html? Also keep in mind this could be bad for search engines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(site|to)/?$ /page [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can redirect to a page in which an iframe fullscreen shows the content of your main page

```
<iframe src="yourpage" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
```